# Ruby HTML unicode to actual characters

Tags: html, ruby, unicode

I am trying to convert HTML numeric character references to a string.
Example:

```
&#12452;&#12473; &#12471;&#12540;&#12488; &#26885;&#23376;
```

To the symbols they represent (sorry if this doesn't render properly for you):
 イス シート 椅子

I've tried the following: `CGI::unescapeHTML(str)` but I still see the numeric character codes rather than the symbols.

I've tried writing the output to a file (just in case it's simply not rendering properly in the terminal) and opening it with TextEdit/vim but that hasn't helped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [htmlentities gem](http://htmlentities.rubyforge.org/). There is also the hex notation to consider (e.g. `&#x30a4;` is the same as `&#12452;` or "イ"). There's no good reason to do this by hand (and probably miss various edge cases and notations that you might not be aware of) when there is a complete and tested library that will do it for you.